# A simple proof of the gradient of the positive part

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Define
$$
u^+:=\max\{0,u\},
$$
prove that
$$
\nabla u^+=\mathbb{1}_{\{u>0\}} \nabla u.
$$
My attempt is to treat each $x \in \Omega.$ So, for $x \in \{u>0\}$ we have $u^+(x)=u(x)$ and $\mathbb{1}_{\{u>0\}}(x)=1.$ So, the identity holds. For $x \notin \{u>0\},$ we have $u^+(x)=0$ and thus $\nabla u^+(x)=0$. In this case, we also have $\mathbb{1}_{\{u>0\}}(x)=0,$ which gives the result.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: You'll need a bit more justifications on how you differentiate your expressions, as in you should explain why you allowed yourself to differentiate on the sets $\{u > 0\}$ and $\{u \leq 0\}$.

Comment: No. With the same reasoning you can prove that $f'(0)=0$ for $f(x):=x$.

Comment: Forgetting about the proof, is the result true? I mean can we express the gradient of the positive part in terms of the indicator function?

Comment: The result itself is true yes.